# fetching data from another website using php

Tags: php, url, get, fetch

I need data from another website using php.
Here is the url where I want to get data .
https://www.bioscopelive.com/en/channel/ekattur-tv

I need this url from the site code .
https://edge4.bioscopelive.com/hls/mfyRkQIBKbdQGlHH3ebIlQ/1536528449/ekattur_tv.m3u8

this code is written in 3314 line.

I am trying to get using this code below

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://www.bioscopelive.com/en/channel/ekattur-tv");

preg_match('/https://edge4.bioscopelive.com/hls/mfyRkQIBKbdQGlHH3ebIlQ/1536528449/ekattur_tv.m3u8/', $content, $url_ch);

echo $ch = $url_ch[0];
```

but I didn't get the url from this script .
Now I want how can I get the 3314 no line url using php.
Thanks to all

Comment: Use error reporting when developing, that `preg_match` is using the delimiter multiple times in the regex

Comment: no its didnt work i need fetch data from line 3314 and get the url

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to. You need to use error reporting, your regex is invalid and won't run. Better yet use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php if you just want to find a known static string.

Comment: As @user3783243 points out - you are using a `delimiter` ( namely `/` ) which itself appears within the pattern.  Besides which the string `mfyRkQIBKbdQGlHH3ebIlQ/1536528449` is probably likely to be dynamic so should not be used in the pattern anyway - perhaps better to search for `.m3u8` in the regex

Comment: ... and escape all `.`s because in regex those are special characters, although unlikely that a string as long as you have would have an alteration of 1-ish character. But `m3u8`s usually are generated with JS so I doubt your PHP will even have that string.